# Looping identifier with condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to somehow make the identifier column exist, is it possible to have like data below?
logic: everytime row of type have the same data, the identifier repeat until there is different type of data, even there are already the same type of data before

```
dt          type    user_id  trx  identifier
2021-08-28  online  100      001  1
2021-08-29  online  100      002  1
2021-08-30  offline 100      003  2
2021-09-04  online  100      004  3
2021-09-08  web     100      005  4
2021-09-09  online  100      006  5
2021-09-11  offline 100      007  6
2021-09-15  offline 100      008  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(new_type), 
  countif(new_type) over(partition by user_id order by trx) as identifier
from (
  select *, ifnull(type != lag(type) over(partition by user_id order by trx), true) as new_type
  from data 
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]